# Chain of observers on Client Server does not update root observer

Tags: java, client, server, observer-pattern

I'm encountering some odd behaviour on my client server java program that uses sockets to send information from client to server. The server needs to implement multiple clients, so when a new client is connected a new thread is run to handle the socket for that client. The problem I am having is that the observer that observes an observer of each socket is not having it's update() method called even though it is called every time a new packet is received by the socket. Here is some code to help.

ServerObserver class:

```
package Server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import Packet.Packet;

public class ServerObserver {

    private Server subject;

    public ServerObserver(Server server) {
        subject = server;
        subject.attach(this);
    }

    public void update() {
        //display packet data
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Server s = null;
        try {
            s = new Server();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ServerObserver so = new ServerObserver(s);
    }

}
```

Server class:

```
package Server;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    private ServerObserver observer;

    static final int PORT_NUM = 1978;
    private ArrayList<SocketServer> clients;

    public Server() throws IOException {
        clients = new ArrayList<SocketServer>();
        serverLoop();
    }

    public ArrayList<SocketServer> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    private void serverLoop() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
        boolean listeningSocket = true;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUM);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port " + PORT_NUM);
        }

        while(listeningSocket) {
            Socket clientSocket = ss.accept();
            SocketServer s = new SocketServer(clientSocket);
            clients.add(s);
            s.attach(this);
            s.start();
        }
        ss.close();
    }

    public void attach(ServerObserver o) {
        observer = o;
    }

    private void notifyObserver() {
        System.out.println("Notifying this Server's observer");
        observer.update();
    }

    public void update() {
        System.out.println("A Socket Server has called update");
        this.notifyObserver();
    }

}
```

SocketServer class:

```
package Server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import Packet.Packet;

public class SocketServer extends Thread {

    private Socket socket = null;
    private Server observer;
    private Packet lastPacket = null;

    public SocketServer(Socket socket) {
        super("SocketServer");
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public Packet getLastPacket() {
        return lastPacket;
    }

    public void attach(Server observer) {
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    public void notifyObserver() {
        System.out.println("Notifying this SocketServer's Observer");
        observer.update();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                    Packet newPacket = null;
                    newPacket = (Packet) ois.readObject();
                    if(newPacket != null) {
                        System.out.println("New packet recieved from client " + newPacket.getClientID());
                        setNewPacket(newPacket);
                        notifyObserver();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.setStackTrace(getStackTrace());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.setStackTrace(getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    public void setNewPacket(Packet packet) {
        lastPacket = packet;
    }

}
```

When this program is run I get the following output from the server:

New packet recieved from client 1234
Notifying this SocketServer's Observer
A Socket Server has called update
Notifying this Server's observer

Now inside of the update() method in Server Observer there are some System.out.println() calls that print out the information inside the Packet. But these are not displayed and I have no idea why.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks.

Comment: Did you call `attach` more than once?

Comment: attach is called on Server and SocketServer to attach the observers to the subjects. Why?

Comment: you might notice that your Server class can only be attached to one observer at a time. Calling `attach` stops the previous one being attached...

Comment: Ohhh I see where I went wrong thanks!